# Different columns for different categories in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I've an SQL table `mobile`. And for different phones I want to save different data. For example in case of touch mobile these columns are required.

- Refresh rate
- Resolution
- Latency

And for other mobiles these columns are required.

- Is black and white
- Screen size

And beside these there are some common columns which are required in both categories like

- Price
- Model

So how do I design this table. Should I create two separate tables? Or just one but then how I handle required attribute for different categories? Or any other method?

Comment: I would suggest just putting all the columns in one table and leaving the values `NULL` when they don't apply.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but the columns for each category are required they cannot be ```NULL```

Comment: You can manage that from front end. If you are inserting information for "Touch Mobile" make related fields mandatory and vise-versa.

Comment: [tag:single-table-inheritance]  and [tag:class-table-inheritance] are two tags that show techniques relevant to your case. If you click on Learn More you will get an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a single table with all those columns along with a new column named MobileType. You might insert 1 for "Touch Mobile" and 0 for "Other Mobile".
If you are inserting information of a "touch mobile" then input 1 in "MobileType" field and all the touch mobile related informations in relative field. Leave "other mobile" related fields as **NULL**. Do the opposite for "other mobile" type entry.

Make **MobileType,Price,Modile** not null field and others Null field and add below constraint which will force your condition:

```
ALTER TABLE mobile ADD CONSTRAINT CK_mobile CHECK(
    Refreshrate is null and Resolution is not null and  Latency  is not null and Isblackandwhite is null and Screensize is null
    OR
    Refreshrate is  null and Resolution is  null and  Latency  is  null and Isblackandwhite is not null and Screensize is not null
    )
```

Comment: That's cool. But how to add these constraints if I'm using ER Diagram?

Answer (score 0):

I would create just one table and manage any required fields through the user interface as part of the data validation. I would not manage that through the table field definitions.

If you really want to create required fields, give them default values which you can then later filter on.

Creating several tables is possible but will easily become cumbersome to manage.